# Need to create tql queries

Tags: java, jython, tquery, cmdb

I need to create TQL queries to query out sets of data from the UCMDB.
I am having 2 problems:

1) How can I find relationships which exists between CIs ( i do not have administrative privileges so need to do it in code somehow)
I need this to get required data.

2) I have created the following query: But I keep getting the IP property value as null.
I checked that IP has an attribute called `ip_address`.
Code:

```
import com.hp.ucmdb.api.types.TopologyRelation;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
     final String HOST_NAME = "192.168.159.132";
     final int PORT = 8080; 

     UcmdbServiceProvider provider = UcmdbServiceFactory.getServiceProvider(HOST_NAME, PORT);

     final String USERNAME = "username";

     final String PASSWORD = "password";

     Credentials credentials = provider.createCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

     ClientContext clientContext = provider.createClientContext("Test");
     UcmdbService ucmdbService = provider.connect(credentials, clientContext);

     TopologyQueryService queryService = ucmdbService.getTopologyQueryService();

     Topology topology = queryService.executeNamedQuery("Host IP");

     Collection<TopologyCI> hosts = topology.getAllCIs(); 

     for (TopologyCI host : hosts) { 


      for (TopologyRelation relation : host.getOutgoingRelations()) { 
       System.out.print("Host " + host.getPropertyValue("display_label")); 
       System.out.println (" has IP " + relation.getEnd2CI().getPropertyValue("ip_address")); 

      } 
     }

}
```

In the above query output: I get the host names with `IP = null`

I have a sample query in JYthon which I am unable to figure out: Its for the above code only.

Attaching it for anyone who can understand it.

```
import sys

UCMDB_API="c:/ucmdb/api/ucmdb-api.jar"

sys.path.append(UCMDB_API)

from com.hp.ucmdb.api import *

# 0) Connection settings
HOST_NAME="192.168.159.132"
PORT=8080

USERNAME="username"
PASSWORD="password"

# 1) Get a Service Provider from the UcmdbServiceFactory
provider = UcmdbServiceFactory.getServiceProvider(HOST_NAME, PORT)

# 2) Setup credentials to log in
credentials = provider.createCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD)

# 3) Create a client context
clientContext = provider.createClientContext("TESTING")

# 4) Connect and retrieve a UcmdbService object
ucmdbService = provider.connect(credentials, clientContext)

# 5) Get the TopologyQueryService from the UcmdbService
queryService = ucmdbService.getTopologyQueryService()

# ======= Everything After this is specific to the query =======

# 6) Execute a Named Query and get the Topology
topology = queryService.executeNamedQuery('Host IP')

# 7) Get the hosts
hosts = topology.getAllCIs()

# 8) Print the hosts and IPs
host_ip = {}

for host in hosts:
    host_name = host.getPropertyValue("display_label")
    if host_name in host_ip.keys():
        ips = host_ip[host_name]
    else:
        ips = {} 
        host_ip[host_name] = ips
    for relation in host.getOutgoingRelations():
        ip_address = relation.getEnd2CI().getPropertyValue("display_label")
        if ip_address in ips.keys():
            pass
        else:
            ips[ip_address] = ''
            print "%s , %s" % (host_name, ip_address)
```

Please help.

I am unable to understand how to go about this further.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest fix would be use the **display_label** property from the IP address CI instead of the ip_address property.  The Jython reference code uses display_label for its logic.

I'd be a little concerned about using display_label since the display_label formatting logic could be changed to no display the IP address for IP CIs.  Getting data directly from the ip_address property is a better choice and should work if the TQL is defined to return that data.  Check the *Host IP* TQL and ensure that it's configured to return ip_address for IP CIs.